# Add Button to ListView dynamically in each row using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` in which I have to show all rows fetched from my database table. Again I have to give two edit and delete buttons in each row. As I am beginner for the same, I tried the following code in XAML-

```
<ListView Height="352" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,90,0,0" Name="Tab1lstProductCategories" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1008">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Category Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}" Width="200"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Created Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}" Width="200"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Updated" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col3}" Width="200"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Edit" Width="200">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Content="Edit" Click="EditCategory" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Delete" Width="200">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteCategory"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

And in C# I Wrote-

```
 DataTable dt=db.Select("select * from ProductCategories");
           for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //Button edit, delete;
            //edit = new Button();
            //edit.Content="Edit";
            //edit.Click += EditCategory;
            //delete= new Button();
            //delete.Content="Delete";
            //delete.Click += DeleteCategory;
            //edit.CommandParameter = dt.Rows[i]["Id"];
            //delete.CommandParameter = dt.Rows[i]["Id"];
            Tab1lstProductCategories.Items.Add(new { Col1 = dt.Rows[i]["CategoryName"], Col2 = dt.Rows[i]["CreatedDate"], Col3=dt.Rows[i]["LastUpdated"]});                
        }



private void EditCategory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button b=sender as Button;
            MessageBox.Show(b.CommandParameter.ToString());
        }

    private void DeleteCategory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

I got the result as-
[image]

I want button over there, Please help me out.

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. You're looking for a `CellTemplate`.

Comment: Bindings will automatically use `ToString()` method to display a content when not given a certain `DataTemplate`. Use a `CellTemplate` for this.

Comment: People should stop binding UI directly to database  ...

Comment: OMG Why in the world are you binding to an anonymous type?? Create a proper data model instead, or use an ORM.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, so I see a couple of issues with your code.

1) You really should create a proper datatype like @HighCore suggested. Looking at your code I assume it will look something like this:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a collection of `ProductCategory` instead of directly adding anonymous types

```
DataTable dt=db.Select("select * from ProductCategories");

// Create a collection for your types
ObservableCollection<ProductCategory> list = new ObservableCollection<ProductCategory>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ProductCategory productCategory = new ProductCategory
    {
        // Casting might be needed here depending on your data types ...
        Id = dt.Rows[i]["Id"],
        CategoryName = dt.Rows[i]["CategoryName"],
        CreatedDate = dt.Rows[i]["CreatedDate"],
        LastUpdated = dt.Rows[i]["LastUpdated"]
    };

    list.Add(productCategory);
}
```

2) You are directly adding item's to the `ListView` which is wrong. What you should be doing is set your collection to be the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView`.

```
Tab1lstProductCategories.ItemsSource = list;
```

3) After using [`CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx) to achieve the `ListView` wanted look through xaml and changing the `DisplayMemberBinding` binding to the appropriate properties, you can bind the `CommandParameter` through the default `{Binding}` expression which will set the command parameter to be the `ProductCategory` item it represents.

```
    <ListView Height="352" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,90,0,0" Name="Tab1lstProductCategories" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1008">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Category Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CategoryName}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Created Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreatedDate}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Updated" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastUpdated}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Edit" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Edit" Click="EditCategory" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Delete" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteCategory" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

From the event handlers - `EditCategory` and `DeleteCategory`, you can extract the Id of the `ProductCategory`

```
private void EditCategory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b=sender as Button;
    ProductCategory productCategory = b.CommandParameter as ProductCategory;
    MessageBox.Show(productCategory.Id);
}
```

This should be sufficient to make your code work, but there are several other points I'd like to make

a. You should highly consider using [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern. this will mean not using event handlers in code behind but using [Commands](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM) instead, and use `CommandParameter` the way it was originally intended to be used.

b. Consider some [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend) framework instead of binding the database directly to your UI. this create incredibly tight coupling which will make your code a lot less reusable, and flexible.

Hope this helps

Comment: How I will add different IDs for different rows for each button?

Comment: Id is the exact name that I have in my table and supposed to bind with it. I have added CommandParameter as you suggested and implemented the EditCategory function as-

private void EditCategory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button b=sender as Button;
            MessageBox.Show(b.CommandParameter.ToString());
        }

But NullPointerException raised as soon as I entered in this function. Why it is happening?

Comment: @PrateekShukla it works for me. It must be something else wrong with your code. Update your question with the updated code so we can check it out

Comment: great solution. What i am missing is the part, where to modify the properties of these buttons. currently there's "only" a general binding with the id. but how can i set properties from the code to the entry of the button in the grid?

Comment: Hi @OmriBtian, fantastic solution! It works for me perfectly, just need to know if there is any possiblity that if any value from a class change in real time, the listview shows such change, only changing the value in the class.